# Sencha Touch Making a simple button work

Tags: javascript, extjs, touch

I have a hard time debugging and understanding why the most basic stuff is going wrong in my sencha project. I use webstorm, but it can't seem to help me much with missspelling code. Most errors i get are unclear like undefined is not a function. Can anyone help me by showing me what I do wrong in the following code. I just want a button that does a console log.

View:

```
    Ext.define('imp.view.Test', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        alias: "widget.test",
        xtype: 'test',
        controllers: 'imp.controller.Test',
        requires: [ 'imp.controller.Test'],

        config: {
            title:'Test',
            scrollable: null,
            items: [

                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    itemId: 'postButton',
                    ui: 'action',
                    padding: '10px',
                    text: 'Post'
                }]


        }

});
```

Controller:

```
Ext.define('imp.controller.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            testView: 'test'
        },
        control: {
            'test #postButton': {
                tap: 'onPostCommand'
            }
        }
    },

        onPostCommand: function (){
            console.log('klik');


        }

    }
);
```

What is a good way to debug and to learn Sencha Touch better, could anyone give me some advice? What books,sites etc. are good?

Update: 
This is the console log output and when i press the butotn just nothing happens.....

```
development.js:21 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
development.js:22 XHR finished loading: GET "http://imp.localhost/imp/bootstrap.json".
development.js:9 GET http://imp.localhost/imp/cordova.js 
sencha-touch.js:13036 The key "minimum-ui" is not recognized and ignored.
Abstract.js?_dc=1427878432368:27 The 'overflowchanged' event is deprecated and may be removed. Please do not use it.
Console.js?_dc=1427878432463:35 [WARN][Anonymous] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'imp.store.Offline.Opdrachten'; consider adding 'imp.store.Offline.Opdrachten' explicitly as a require of the corresponding class
sencha-touch.js:8381 XHR finished loading: GET "http://imp.localhost/imp/app/store/Offline/Opdrachten.js?_dc=1427878433743".
sencha-touch.js:8381 XHR finished loading: GET "http://imp.localhost/touch/src/data/ArrayStore.js?_dc=1427878433755".
sencha-touch.js:8381 XHR finished loading: GET "http://imp.localhost/touch/src/data/reader/Array.js?_dc=1427878433767".
Console.js?_dc=1427878432463:35 [WARN][Anonymous] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'imp.store.Offline.Antwoorden'; consider adding 'imp.store.Offline.Antwoorden' explicitly as a require of the corresponding class
sencha-touch.js:8381 XHR finished loading: GET "http://imp.localhost/imp/app/store/Offline/Antwoorden.js?_dc=1427878433786".
Connection.js?_dc=1427878433330:375 GET https://simplemanager.transfer-solutions.com/ords/simplemanager/test1/planningen 401 (Unauthorized)
Connection.js?_dc=1427878433330:375 XHR finished loading: GET "https://simplemanager.transfer-solutions.com/ords/simplemanager/test1/planningen".
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in your browsers console window? This is usually the best way to debug JS issues as most of them will only occur under certain conditions or in response to a particular event.

Comment: No errors at all. It's just not working....

Comment: I familiar with Javascript debugging however Sencha seems to be a different kind with it's own issues...

Comment: yes, you have the sencha ecosystem to deal with, you need to be familiar with how it works. Its difficult to debug your code without being able to replicate the issues, could you create a fiddle at fiddle.sencha.com ?

Comment: Best way to debug is to use the developer tool and to use console.log. Console.log has been immense help to me in building sencha touch app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find out if there is something wrong with your code is using Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in Chrome.

Referring to your problem, I just removed the `util.Utility` from the code and it works fine. So you want to make sure if there is any `Utility.js` in the `app/util` folder. Also, `Utility.js` should follow Sencha class structure:

```
Ext.define('.util.Utility', { /*upper case "U" in important*/
      config : {
      }
});
```

At the end, you should see either the `klik` or an error in the console output.

Comment: I did just that but it does not help anything. I don't understand why it works with you and not with me. Could you show me your sencha fiddle? I indeed have a Utility.js in that folder...

Comment: @Robert My code is identical to yours. I just remove the `Utility.js` declaration. I think you should take a look at the Console output for possible errors and if you can copy the output here for more examination.
I also update the answer take a look.

Comment: I removed the utility and added console output in de post.

Comment: @Robert It seems that the error is outside of the View and Controller.
First, to make sure you setup Sencha correctly, try to run some code samples which can be found online.
Second, if samples run without any problem. Add the other project files to question. Goodluck.